# Prove if $\dim(\ker(T))=n-1$ then $T$ has at most 2 distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ vector space with $\dim(V)=n$, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ a linear operator such that $$\dim(\ker(T))=n-1$$

**Prove:** $T$ has at most 2 distinct eigenvalues.

I know that $\dim(\mathrm{im}(T))=1$ and it has to do with geometric multiplicty for finding an upper limit, but I don't know.

I'd appreciate a full exact proof in order to learn perfect writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you denote $E_\lambda$ the eigenspace relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ the simple observation is that
$$
\ker(T)=E_0
$$
Since eigenspaces are linearly independent, the hypothesis $\dim(\ker(T))=n-1$ leaves space for at most one more $1$-dimensional eigenspace, hence for at most one eigenvalue $\lambda\neq0$.

Comment: Perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $n=1$, then $T$ has exactly one eigenvalue, since $T(v)=av$ for some scalar $a$.

Otherwise, $\ker T\neq\{0\}$ and therefore $0$ is an eigenvalue. If $T$ has two *other* distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be eigenvectors whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. Then, $T(v_1)=\lambda_1v_1$ and $T(v_2)=\lambda_2v_2$ and therefore $v_1,v_2\in\operatorname{Im}T$. So, $\dim\operatorname{Im}T\geqslant 2$ and, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\ker T\leqslant n-2$.

Comment: In your answer, can $0$ be an eigenvalue?

Comment: It **is** an eigenvalue (when $n>1$).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $n>1$, then $0$ is an eigenvalue. Let $v$ be a generator of the image $T(v)=cv$. Let $w$ another eigenvalue. Write $w=u+av, u\in ker(T) $, $T(w) =aT(v) $ implies that $w=av$.